# Clearing search in Mac Mail for 11.1 Big Sur by selecting another mailbox

Tags: macos, mail.app

Previous to Big Sur I could clear the search field in Mac Mail by selecting a different mailbox. Now in Big Sur when I select another mailbox the search is still applied.

Is there any way to change the functionality back to clearing the search when changing the focused mailbox?

Comment: Never knew that such feature existed, but then I have always used ⌥ + ⌘ + F shortcut to go to search field and used backspace there to clear it if necessary.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I've been doing (⌥ + ⌘ + F then esc), a bit cumbersome, but better than searching for the "x" to clear the field.